# What is the name of this tree? - currently a bonsai

Tags: identification, trees, bonsai

I'm trying to find the name of this tree. It's currently a bonsai and isn't doing very well, indoors or out. It came with no identification and very basic instructions like "don't let it dry out." Hoping if I know the type I can better care for it.

I'm the kind of person who feels sad when a houseplant dies. Losing a bonsai would be like killing a relative...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's a [Japanese Zelkova (*Zelkova serrata*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelkova_serrata).

Comment: Oooh it's deciduous. So it's probably fine. Just dropping all its leaves. And here I was freaking out.

Comment: @user1066609 What season is it where you are?

Comment: And what location.  It should only be inside if the winters are too harsh for it outside.

Comment: I've got a japanese zelkova bonsai, and the leaves in the OPs picture look too thick and stiff, and the serrations aren't pointy enough.

Comment: @standgale Yeah, there are a lot of variations.